# Protocol used by iPhone when connecting to a stereo via USB?

Tags: iphone, ipod, usb

What is the protocol used by iPod/iPhone when connecting to a stereo via USB?  Is it [PTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol) or some other proprietary protocol?